# What is meant by a "critical system"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, condensed-matter

I see "critical system" being used all the time. For example:

> Excellent candidates for this approach
> are systems exhibiting phase transitions. At the critical
> point of a phase transition, the eigenstates of the system are extremely sensitive to any changes of the system
> parameters [29–32]. If the final state of such a protocol
> is the ground state of the system, it will be immune to
> dissipation as the ground state is the lowest energy state.
> In this manuscript, we show that critical metrology is
> not only robust...

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_phenomena and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(thermodynamics)

Comment: It just means the system is at a critical point / line (e.g., a phase transition, where there are correlations on all length scales).